# Evaluation of loss with session.run([]) in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

For simple gradient descent, I am using this :

`_, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction])`
 where optimizer op minimizes loss.

But I am feeding loss after optimizer, so will the loss, be evaluated two times at each .run(), one using initial weight, and then using updated weights ?

Comment: It will be evaluated once, but unless you use control edges (with_dependencies), the result is non-deterministic -- it may evaluate loss before updating the variables, or after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of elements in the list of fetched tensors doesn't matter (except for capturing the values on the Python side). They will all be executed during the same evaluation.

In your example, the loss will be evaluated only once and any computations that can be shared between the `[optimizer, loss, train_prediction]` will be shared.