# Does Tensorflow 1.xx cache intermediate results of ops?

Tags: python, tensorflow

let's say that in TF 1.xx we have a simple network in which we first have an op to calculate the loss during training, and then this tensor is passed to an optimizer that performs gradient updates given that loss. We then want the value of the loss and also to execute the optimization step, so we do something like:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(target, prediction))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
_, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I have two questions:

1. Will we make two forward passes on the network to execute the two ops? One to calculate the loss, and one to run the train_op (who in turn needs the loss), or is the loss "cached"?
2. Do we have a race condition between the loss and train_op? If TF does not guarantee the order of execution inside sess.run(), am I sure that the loss op will give the result of the loss before the optimization step, always?

Also, what is the best way to answer the question? Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the sequence for tensorflow's session to run a list of tensors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725512/what-is-the-sequence-for-tensorflows-session-to-run-a-list-of-tensors)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for redirecting. It's similar, the conclusion that the author makes in the Update on the question seems to point out that for 2) there is no race condition, right? Though it does not answer whether we make two forward passes or not.

Comment: See the comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35457879/5154274) and the answer

Comment: Thank you! I think this clarifies it.